# Replacing a string by an integer dictionary in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe.

```
        epi_week    state   loc_type    disease    cases    incidence
21835   200011      WY      STATE       MUMPS       2       0.40
21836   197501      WY      STATE       POLIO       3       0.76
21837   199607      WY      STATE       HEPATITIS   3       0.61
21838   197116      WY      STATE       MUMPS       6       1.73
21839   200048      WY      STATE       HEPATITIS   6       1.21
```

I am trying to replace each `disease` by a unique integer. For example `'MUMPS'==1`, `'POLIO'==2` etc. The final dataframe should look like follows:

```
        epi_week    state   loc_type    disease    cases    incidence
21835   200011      WY      STATE       1          2        0.40
21836   197501      WY      STATE       2          3        0.76
21837   199607      WY      STATE       3          3        0.61
21838   197116      WY      STATE       1          6        1.73
21839   200048      WY      STATE       3          6        1.21
```

I am using the following code:

```
# creating a dictionary     
disease_dic = {'MUMPS':1, 'POLIO':2, 'MEASLES':3, 'RUBELLA':4,
               'PERTUSSIS':5, 'HEPATITIS A':6, 'SMALLPOX':7, 
               'DIPHTHERIA':8}
data.disease = [disease_dic[item] for item in data.disease]
```

I am getting following errors:

```
KeyErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-115-52394901c90d> in <module>()
----> 1 cdc.disease = [disease_dic[item2] for item2 in cdc.disease]

KeyError: 1
```

Can anyone please help about this issue? Thank you.

Comment: use `data.disease = data.disease.map(disease_dic)`

Comment: the key represent by `item2` doesn't seem to exist in the dict at some point.

Comment: it was a typo when i was writing in here. correct line is `data.disease = [disease_dic[item2] for item2 in data.disease]`

Comment: @jezral using `data.disease = data.disease.map(disease_dic)` gives `NaN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `apply`.

**Ex:**

```
disease_dic = {'MUMPS':1, 'POLIO':2, 'MEASLES':3, 'RUBELLA':4,
               'PERTUSSIS':5, 'HEPATITIS A':6, 'SMALLPOX':7, 
               'DIPHTHERIA':8}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"disease": disease_dic.keys()})
print(df["disease"].apply(lambda x: disease_dic.get(x)))
```

**Output:**

```
0    4
1    2
2    1
3    8
4    3
5    5
6    7
7    6
Name: disease, dtype: int64
```